# AWS STS to list buckets gives access denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, assume-role

I have a bucket with empty bucket policy, block public access turned ON (ACLs and Bucket) and trying to list buckets using IAM policy tied to user using STS AssumeRole with following attached policy.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetBucket*",
                "s3:ListBucket*",
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-test-bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The assumed role credentials are used during the STS session in python (boto3)

```py
s3c = boto3.client('s3',
  aws_access_key_id=credentials['AccessKeyId'],
  aws_secret_access_key=credentials['SecretAccessKey'],
  aws_session_token=credentials['SessionToken'])

s3c.list_buckets()
```

I get this exception:

> botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListBuckets operation: Access Denied

When I tried to use IAM Policy simulator, it indicates "Implicitly denied". Im thinking if I need to access a bucket policy for this user? My understanding has been if both IAM and Bucket policy, it is an intersection. If either is not present, the other takes precedence.

Comment: ListBucket action requires permissions on the bucket. In your case, the IAM policy is missing that. So, in the resources section, can you add this as well and try: `"arn:aws:s3:::my-test-bucket"`? There is a section in this document that explains it: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-how-to-grant-access-to-an-amazon-s3-bucket/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling `list_buckets()` uses the `s3:ListAllMyBuckets` permission.

This permission cannot be restricted to a specific bucket. A user can either list *all* of the buckets in the account, or none of them.

Calling **operations on a bucket** (`ListBucket, GetBucket*`) requires permission for the bucket itself.

**Operations on objects** requires permission for the objects (or `/*` after the bucket name to permit actions on all objects).

Therefore, you can change your policy to:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucket*"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-test-bucket"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-test-bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I had read during assumerole, but realised too late that the resulting session's permission are an intersection of the role's identity policy (IAM) + session policy. If there is a resource policy, then that is include as well. So I ensure the policy attached to the role is broad (resource:"*") Here is additional info https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sts/assume-role.html and scroll down to the "Permissions" section.

Answer (score -1):

This is a pretty common issue because people tend to miss the difference between a "bucket" resource and an "object" resource. A bucket ends in the name of the bucket (`arn:aws:s3:::my-test-bucket`) whereas an object includes the bucket and key, and is often granted with a star after the initial slash. So, just change your policy to the following.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-test-bucket"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetBucket*",
                "s3:ListBucket*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-test-bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: List all buckets does not allow a resource limit